# Automatically set SUM calculation's result as column value during / after row insert

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an SQL table called "credits" which contain the following columns:

- id (Serial ID for rows (1,2,3,....))
- account_id (ID of associated client)
- change (int4)
- rolling_change

Every time during/after a row insert, I'd like the result of this Query to be the "rolling_change" column's value:

```
SELECT SUM(change)
FROM credits
WHERE account_id = {account_id} AND id < {this_id};
```

How can I make this process happen automatically on every row insert?

(I'm using DBeaver for reference)

Comment: I believe you should use a view instead of storing the sum in a separated column, as a non-key attribute shouldn't depend on another non-key attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that updates the empty rolling_change after inserts.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE credits (
>     id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
>     account_id  INT NOT NULL,
>     change      INT NOT NULL, 
>     rolling_change INT
> );
> ```

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc_credits_rolling_change() 
> RETURNS trigger AS $calc_rolling_change$
> BEGIN
>     UPDATE credits tgt
>     SET rolling_change = src.rolling_change
>     FROM (
>         SELECT id
>         , SUM(change) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id 
>                             ORDER BY id) AS rolling_change
>         FROM credits
>     ) src
>     WHERE src.id = tgt.id
>       AND tgt.rolling_change IS NULL;
>
>     RETURN NEW;
> END;
> $calc_rolling_change$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER trg_credits_rolling_change
>   AFTER INSERT
>   ON credits
>   EXECUTE PROCEDURE calc_credits_rolling_change();
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO credits (account_id, change) VALUES
>   (1, 1), (1, 0)
> , (2, 1), (2, 1), (2, 0);
>
> INSERT INTO credits (account_id, change) VALUES
>   (3, 2), (3, 1), (1, 10)
> ```

> ```
> select * from credits order by account_id, id;
> ```

| id | account_id | change | rolling_change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 | 10 | 11 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 | 1 | 3 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=18d3f9547986b3fc9b74ce85d8b109cb)*